# prepare() function doesn't work well in migrate module

Tags: nodes, migrations

This is my code to move a few records from a table to a Drupal content type (called CT1)

```
<?php 
class CT1Migration extends Migration {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(MigrateGroup::getInstance());
        $this->description = 'Imports CT1';
        $fields = array(
                'id',
                'subject',
                'content',
        );

        $query = db_select('tbl', 'qf')
        ->fields('qf', $fields);

        $this->source = new MigrateSourceSQL($query);

        $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationNode('porseman');

        $pkmap = array('id' => array('type'  => 'int',
                'unsigned'  => TRUE,
                'not null'  => TRUE,
                'alias'     => 'qf'));

        $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName, $pkmap, MigrateDestinationNode::getKeySchema());
        $this->addFieldMapping('title','subject');
        $this->addFieldMapping('field_CT_body', 'content')->arguments(array('format' => 'full_html'));
    }

    public function prepare($row) {
        $row->title = "This is title 1";
        $row->field_CT_body = t("This is body"); 
    }
}
?>
```

CT1 has two fields, `title` and `body`. I need to perform some settings before the migration so I use `prepare()` function. From `function prepare($row)` function I expect the values of `title` and `field_CT_body` of all of the imported records to be `This is title 1` and `This is body` while after the migration the `title` correctly gets this string (`This is title 1`) as its value but `field_CT_body` has no value at all.

if I remove the `prepare` function it migrates the records successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't set the value directly like that, you need to reference the language and delta in the classic, hated method:

```
public function prepare($entity, stdClass $row) {
  $row->title = "This is title 1";
  $row->field_CT_body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = t("This is body");
}
```

Note: This function takes [2 params](https://www.drupal.org/node/1132582), the entity object being built and the source row. So, since we're altering the entity object, we gotta manipulate it as such.  (I'm not sure, but you might be able to wrap that object in a [metadata wrapper](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers) in order to use the cleaner API)

Also, please note that the "value" key will depend on the field type in use.

Note: untested code but it should be fine! :)

Comment: I always appreciate `meta data wrapper` !

Comment: what is the "value"? the field type is `long text`

Comment: I tried `$row->field_CT_body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = array('value' => t("This is body"));` but the original data from source was moved not the `This is body`

Comment: The easiest way is to edit an existing node yourself to get set the value you want and inspect it using the Devel module to see what the data structure is for that field. Text ones usually have "value" as the only key, others like date have a whole plethora of keys, check it out!

Comment: it was `$row->field_CT_body['und'][0]['value']`

Comment: good catch, i'm updating my answer

Comment: I find using the _exact_ function signature as in the Docs helpful https://www.drupal.org/node/1132582 eg, `function prepare($entity, stdClass $row)` it helps you to understand whether $row is an array at this instance, or an plain object.